# Is it possible in C# to deserialize json so that a field in the json instantiates a particular subclass that has overridden functions?

Tags: c#, json, reflection, deserialization, json-deserialization

Let's say you have the following portion of json:

```
{ "Behavior": "BehaviorTypeA" }
```

When you deserialize json, the deserializer will essentially import the data from the json text to a class definition, which could be like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Behavior { get; set; }
}
```

But let's say that you wanted that data to indicate some kind of behavior, so perhaps your class definition might instead be

```
public class MyClass
{
    public BaseBehavior Behavior { get; set; }
}
```

Where you also have the definitions

```
public class BaseBehavior
{
    public abstract void DoIt();
}
```

And

```
public class BehaviorTypeA : BaseBehavior
{
    public override void DoIt()
    {
        // some functionality
    }
}
```

Is this possible with json deserialization, and if so, what would the json have to be and how would it be done?  Might it possibly require a custom deserializer and possibly added reflection code?  (The BaseBehavior class doesn't have to be abstract and might contain member fields.)

Comment: I think it would be much cleaner if you would separate the json parsing from object creation. Read the value of `Behaviour` as a string and use reflection to create a new instance with `Activator.CreateInstance`.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can always inject your own JsonConverter with custom logic to instantiate the class you want, with the functionality you want.

I think you could accomplish this even more easily with this library: https://github.com/manuc66/JsonSubTypes

Assuming you’re using Newtonsoft.Json, here is some info on fully custom JsonConverters: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

You’re essentially following a kind of strategy pattern, where each behavior you want will need to exist as it’s own class, then you could cobble together any set of behaviors based on their names.

Comment: Upon reading your question again, I think JaonSubTypes may not be the *best* way to go. A custom converter is probably your best bet